# Unwanted navigation when tapping OptionsMenu Item in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, optionmenu

My application has one Activity and several fragments. Navigation Component was used for navigation and it is not very complicated. Also BottomNavigationComponent was used for bottom navigation. 
There are three top level fragments which can be accessed via bottom navigation and there is an options menu at one of the top level fragments. Also this is not a complicated menu,too; there is just one item.

So, this is not a big deal and created menu like below.

**notifications_menu**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dismiss_all"
        android:title="@string/dismiss_all"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

**NotificationsFragment.kt**

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        viewModel =
            ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory().create(NotificationsViewModel::class.java)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
        (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)
//other stuff
}
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.notifications_menu, menu)
}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == R.id.dismiss_all) {
          // there is no code here yet
          return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And here is the result...
[image: problem gif]

The problem is, as you can see above, when I tap Dismiss All button it navigates to the initial fragment. But I couldn't understand why?

Comment: I couldn't understand the reason of down vote. If you are planning to give down vote please explain your reason a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging two hours I found that MainActivity's onOptionsItemSelected is causing this situation. Because as you can see it is handling all menu items and call onBackPressed event.

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        if (menuItem != null) {
            onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)
    }
```

Handling correctly this method solved my problem.
Here is the correct version of the code above.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    val id = menuItem?.itemId
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)
}
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be handling `android.R.id.home` in `onOptionsItemSelected()` anyways - that's what `onSupportNavigateUp()` is for.

Comment: Hmm, so you say I don’t need to override onOptionsItemsSelected in the activity, right?

Comment: `super.onOptionsItemSelected()` will call `onSupportNavigateUp()` for `android.R.id.home` already, yes.

Comment: @ianhanniballake interestingly I realized if I remove the code that you say, OnBackPressedCallbacks are not triggered when action bar's back button pressed. so I leave it there. Do you know why it behaves like this?

Comment: up and back are different, yes. The point I was making is that you should move your code to `onSupportNavigateUp()`, not remove it entirely.

Comment: I think you must override onOptionsItemSelected like that : 



```if (onBackPressedDispatcher.hasEnabledCallbacks())
                        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
else
                        navController.navigateUp()```

Comment: @faskN I will try and let you know. Thanks